# Compressing multiple files without directory

Tags: python, zip

I'm trying to compress multiple files using Pyminizip model (need to set a password for the zip). I want the zip to be flat - instead, the zip is compressed with the directory where the files located.

```
dirs = os.listdir(tempDirPath)

lst = [ u'/tempDirPath', u'/tempDirPath', u'/tempDirPath', u'/tempDirPath', u'/tempDirPath', u'/tempDirPath', u'/tempDirPath', u'/tempDirPath' ,u'/tempDirPath', u'/tempDirPath', u'/tempDirPath', u'/tempDirPath', u'/tempDirPath', u'/tempDirPath', u'/tempDirPath']

pyminizip.compress_multiple(dirs ,lst, newname, "password", 6 )
```

The zip is created but with the parent directory - "tempDir" in it, 
how can I avoid it and create a flat zip? I saw a solution which mentions 'arcname', but it only valid for comprising each file separately.

Comment: Try passing `[]` instead of `lst` to `pyminizip.compress_multiple`.

Comment: it works, many thanks!!